# Change the way Join Operator renames like columns

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

Is there a way to change the way the Join Operator appends a '1' at the end of columns that have the same name across both join tables? I would like to do this without renaming the columns explicitly.

```
datatable(TableKey:string, CreatedDate:datetime)
['1', datetime('2022-01-01')]
| join kind=inner (
    datatable(TableKey:string, CreatedDate:datetime)
    ['1', datetime('2022-01-02')]
    ) on TableKey
```

Result:

```
TableKey    CreatedDate                  TableKey1   CreatedDate1
1           2022-01-01 00:00:00.0000000  1           2022-01-02 00:00:00.0000000
```

Comment: What would be your alternative solution to avoid column names' clashes?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz, not sure I have an alternate solution.... hence the original question.  IF it was up to me I would add an optional parameter to the join operator that allows users to choose how to deal with column name clashes; such as append text of the users choosing.

Typically, I am doing queries with very little time to be thorough so it would be nice to have the option without reviewing the columns before-hand.

Comment: Personally, I would prefer the join keys the be projected only once. There seems to be nothing to do with a duplicated column other than removing it ASAP. As for the rest of the columns, it might be an interesting approach to add the table name / sub-query alias to all fields in both sides of the JOIN.